# In an online chess game, how to minimize the effect of lag to time controls?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time, chess

I'm planing to write a small web app where two players can play a chess game with blitz time controls. Here's a small description of how the process of making a move works:

1. Player A thinks about what move to make
2. Player A sends a move to my server
3. My server processes the request
4. My server sends a response to the push server
5. The push server processes the request
6. The push server sends a response to player B
7. Player B thinks about what move to make

It makes sense that step 1 will be running on player A's allotted time and step 7 will be running on player B's allotted time. What can I do about the other steps? Is there any way to measure how much time those other steps took and maybe to add the result to both players' clocks?

Comment: The server should know the "exact" times and should send these to the client(s) -- the client(s) keep track of local times, which could be marginally off due to latency. Then just define which time gets put on which clock. e.g. server-RECIEVER to server-SEND? (Player A is penalized a little bit on send, player B a little bit on receive? Assuming equal latency it should balance...)

Comment: In my opinion you should ignore the time it takes for one player's move to reach the other's browser, otherwise your web app latency would be "stealing" game time (in the case the chess clock is setting a time requirement to finish the game). Add to each player's clock only the time they took from receiving the other player's move (step 6) until making their own move (step 2).

Comment: This is kind of the two phase commit problem. The server knows the timestamp for when it sent the message, but does *not* know if and when the client recieved the message. This could be implemented by augmenting the protocol to acknowledge the reception of messages. The server could then calculate the round-trip time (this assumes the clients can be trusted, since timestamps could be forged) . Normally a time-bonus (say: 1 sec) is added to the player's clock for every move made.

Comment: I like your idea, @ThomasC.G.deVilhena, this means that each player will see his own clock behave without lag. However, when will player A's information about player B's clock be updated? When player A thinks that it's player B's turn, player A should see player B's clock ticking, and when player A receives information from the push server that player B made a move, that information should be used to update player A's view of B's clock? If so, there's also the problem of player B lying about his thinking time, but I suppose that can be prevented by obfuscating the client side script.

Comment: @wildplasser what you're describing seems to be used in an environment where the client's processing time is negligible; in a turn-based game, player A could take 3 seconds to respond, player B could take 30, and in fact player B might have less lag than A. I suppose I could have the server ask the client to respond with a couple of instant requests so that the server could compute an average round-trip, but when a client will have a problem and his latency will suddenly rise, the server will believe that the client is taking that time to think about the move, which is unfortunate.

Comment: It is not about the *processing* time; it is only about aknowledging the *reception* of the message. The client can start thinking after the acknowledge. But again: the problem is *basically* insolvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done without trusting the client.

The basic problem is that a client with low latency can pretend to have a high latency in order to gain bonus time. A client with 100ms of round trip latency may pretend to have a 3s RTT and use this deception to turn a 6.9s move into a 4s move. There is no practical way for a protocol to detect a client pretending to have high latency, unless the client makes a mistake (e.g. asking for a 3s delay waiver when they took 1s to make their move).

On the other hand, if you do trust the client, you can just estimate their RTT by pinging their machine periodically and deducting that time from their move time. If you *really* trust the client, have them measure and report the elapsed time with the move data.

There are a lot of ways to manage this trust/latency-penalty tradeoff. You can assume a minimum RTT (50ms?) and deduct that from everything. You can put bonus time on the clocks. You can have the user-facing option of a game being 'secure' vs 'forgiving'.

Answer (score 0):

I've went for Thomas C. G. de Vilhena's idea in the end. In summary:
 - the time is measured for each player starting from when he is informed that he has to play and ending when he sends the move to the server
 - the time remaining for the opponent is adjusted when the player is informed on the opponent's move
 - to prevent users from cheating the javascript that sends the move will be obfuscated and the server response will be encrypted
 - a time correction routine is necessary in case players exceed the time alloted
 - (optional) a mechanism will be available to each player to detect any (unlikely) attempt of cheating, resulting in logging that hopefuly will allow an arbiter to decide on which side the cheating occured

This insures that a player will see that the server respects his thinking time, and no player will suffer from lag.