# Is there a harder to break way to obfuscate a javascript function than hieroglyphy?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I'm developing an online chess variant game. I want to create a javascript function that has the purpose of communicating to the server on behalf of the player the exact time spent on a move.

This message will be encrypted, of course, but in order to trust this function, I want to obfuscate it to the point that I can rely on the obfuscation algorithm.

I only know a few obfuscation algorithms, [hieroglyphy](http://patriciopalladino.com/files/hieroglyphy/) being the most interesting. But it isn't unbreakable. Speed of execution and size are not critical, I can deduct the time spent by the function that sends the message in that same function, and the size can be even up to 2MB.

I'm pretty sure that there is no unbreakable algorithm because as long as it is required to run in a browser, anyone with enough patience can take it piece by piece and see what it does.

Do I have an alternative that would require more effort and time from a user with bad intentions?

**Edit** I've done some tests in every browser on WindowsXP and it appears that in FF, IE, Opera and Chrome the `setTimeout` function will trigger after a delay that is passed as the second parameter, **regardless of any changes to system time during the delay**. If no other information is presented to suggest otherwise, the logical conclusion would be that time can be measured client-side regardless of system time changes, using the setTimeout function but not the Date() object, up to a precision given by the setTimeout delay time.

Hamish mentioned in an answer below that modifying the browser date/time APIs is trivial. In that case, the javascript code is vulnerable to a modification that will increase the setTimeout real delay time. Some code should be set in place so that the server should start suspecting of cheating someone who has unreasonable lag time. This will always be a problem if lag time isn't included in thinking time.

There's a reason I can't use server side timing. The lag times would sometimes exceed a reasonable amount and that will leave users dissatisfied. And sometimes the lag can make all the difference.

Which brings me back to the original question. I'm looking for the best obfuscation method, where best is measured in the effort an attacker has to make to deobfuscate. Ideally, I would want to change the obfuscation algorithm faster than an attacker can deobfuscate, and then never to use that algorithm again or use it rarely, at a time the attacker won't expect.

Comment: And also note that the users that have bad intentions are also the ones that have all the effort and time needed.

Comment: Hieroglyphy is fun, but extremely easy to get back your original code.  When you want to defeat reverse engineering, you need to obfuscate the **logic** of your code, mangling it so much that the person can't easily find which function does the encryption. Mind you that I've said to obfuscate your code's logic, not to obfuscate your code itself -- which can always be put back in a form that resembles the original program. I've found that the Closure Compiler's Advanced Mode (not Simple Mode) works great in this area.

Comment: @Stephen Chung you make an excellent point, please consider adding an answer. If you have more ways to obfuscate code than Closure Compiler's Advanced Mode, please consider adding them as well to your answer

Answer (score 4):

I could set my computer's clock to three hours ago and your script would happily send `-10800 seconds`. NEVER rely on JavaScript to handle information in a trusted manner. Use your server-side code to time the difference between when the player's turn started and when they made their move, and absolutely keep a representation of the game on the server and make sure the move is valid.

Comment: Agree.  If altvali's server wants to know how long the white player took to move, it can record when it sent them black's move, and record when it gets white's move back, and take the difference.  That way, you don't have to worry about your client being hacked - you don't need any custom encryption at all.  (You might want to use SSL to protect the user's password, in case they used the same password on other sites).

Comment: @user9876 the solution you're proposing has one caveat: the server will include the lag time in the time it measures. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965051/in-an-online-chess-game-how-to-minimize-the-effect-of-lag-to-time-controls

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscating your code doesn't help, for two reasons:

1. Users can still inspect the messages being sent from the browser to the server. You would also have to sign the message somehow, to prevent it being intercepted and modified. Generally, it will be even easier to unpack the message than the function used to generate it.
2. You're trying to measure the time taken on the move, which means your obfuscated function still has to trust the system clock *and* the browser date/time APIs. Both are trivial to modify.

A sensible solution would be to measure the time messages are sent and received on your server, and measure the latency of the connection to correct for transmission speeds (if you need to be *very* accurate).

Comment: About point #1: I've mentioned that the message will be encrypted. Point #2 though... it gives me something new to ponder

Comment: Yes, but consider that your encryption method is available, so if you can figure out the message structure, you can encrypt it (even with no knowledge of how the encryption is implemented). Which means you have to obfuscate everything internal that handles the messaging. Lot of work for not a lot of protection.